# How to run 32-bit .exe of Battlefield 4 on 64-bit machine?

Tags: battlefield-4, origin

Okay, I have 64-bit Windows installed in my PC.

I would like to run the 32-bit version `bf4_x86.exe` of this game as I have [found](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/32-bit-version-has-far-better-performance-than-64-bit-on-Win-7/td-p/1762979) that 32-bit version has much better performance. I am facing stuttering issue with my game actually.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Why don't you jsut run `bf4_x86.exe` ? x86 is 32 bit.

Comment: When I double click any of these two files (`bf4.exe` or `bf4_x86.exe`) it opens up the browser and points me to battlelog.com. Then when I launch campaign or join a server it automatically opens up the 64-bit version `bf4.exe`

Comment: Have you tried going into my games section of Origin, right click on the bf4 icon and then select game properties, and select 32 bit (x86)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution! :D

1. Open origin
2. Right click on the game and chose **Game Properties...**
3. Chose the version from **When launching this game** dropdown menu.

*Screenshot*
[image]

Comment: It was said how to do it right there in the thread you linked in the question.